# Passar parâmetro para a segunda activity

Tags: android

Estou tentando passar algum parâmetro para outra activity, mas o aplicativo trava na segunda tela. O nome do aplicativo é calculadora. O erro que diz na segunda tela é: Calculadora parou.

Seguem os códigos:

xml da activity principal:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    android:orientation="vertical"  
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}">  

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tx1"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:text="valor 1"/>  

    <EditText  
        android:id="@+id/edt1"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>  

    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/tx2"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:text="valor 2"/>  

    <EditText  
        android:id="@+id/edt2"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>  

    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/btn1"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:text="calcular"/>  

</LinearLayout>
```

Classe da activity:

```
package com.estudos.calculadora;  

import android.app.Activity;  
import android.content.Intent;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;  
import android.widget.Button;  
import android.widget.EditText;  
import android.widget.TextView;  

public class MainActivity extends Activity {  

@Override  
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
final TextView tx1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tx1);  

final EditText edt1 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt1);  

TextView tx2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tx2);  

final EditText edt2 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt2);  

Button calcular =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);  

calcular.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  

@Override  
public void onClick(View v) {  
double valor1=Double.parseDouble(edt1.getText().toString());  
double valor2=Double.parseDouble(edt2.getText().toString());  
Double soma=valor1+valor2;  

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity_tela2.class);  

intent.putExtras("soma", soma);  

        startActivity(intent);  
}  
});  
}  

}
```

xml da segunda acitivy:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    android:orientation="vertical"  
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}">  

    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/resultado"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:text="resultado"/>  

    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/vtn_volta"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:text="voltar"/>  

</LinearLayout>
```

código da classe:

```
package com.estudos.calculadora;  

import android.app.Activity;  
import android.content.Intent;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;  
import android.widget.Button;  
import android.widget.TextView;  

public class Activity_tela2 extends Activity {  

@Override  
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela2);  

Intent intent = getIntent();  

TextView resultado =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultado);  

Button btn_volta =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_volta);  
}  

}
```

Ainda não tratei o onclick do botão voltar. Só quero entender porque ainda não consigo ir para a segunda tela.

Comment: Aparentemente no layout da segunda activity ao invés de btn_volta está declarado vtn_volta.

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque o log de erros.

Answer (score -1):

Ao criar a Intent faça assim:

`Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), Classe_Tela2.class);
i.putExtra("soma", soma);
startActivity(i);`

E na segunda activity, faça o seguinte:

`Bundle receptor = getActivity().getExtras();
//depois é só receber os valores usando Bundle (receptor)`

Comment: O que é esse `v` e `Classe_Tela2`?

Comment: Classe_Tela2 é uma referência que usei para a segunda Activity. E `v` e do parâmetro do método `onClick(View v)`

Mas pela explicação que recebi, isso não tem relevância alguma!

Comment: O que você propõe é idêntico ao que o AP está a fazer. Sem saber qual é o erro, qualquer resposta é "chute".

Answer (score -2):

Voce errou nessa linha amigo:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity_tela2.class);
```

Deve ser assim:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, Activity_tela2.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Ou seja, primeiro voce cria uma nova intent com o metodo `new Intent()`, só depois usa o metodo `setClass` para definir a Activity atual e qual Activity voce quer ir.

Comment: Isso não resolve o problema, essas duas formas são [equivalentes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E)).

Answer (score -2):

No Java, "valor é diferente de Valor" e "VaLoR é diferente de VALOR"
.
Nessa linha onde declaras a variável soma, colocaste *Double*, tente colocar *double*.

Tipo:
`*double* soma = valor1 + valor2;`
E não
`*Double* soma = valor1 + valor2;`

Comment: Se fosse um problema de sintaxe ou de tipo ele era detectado na compilação.